# How to use a collapsible menu when select value in a drop down list

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I want to show 2 drop down lists when selecting a value in another drop down list. It should be shown in a collapsible manner (no need to expand drop down lists). I have no  idea to do it. A little example with the code will be enough to understand the concept of how it works.

Here is an example of what I expect. But in this there should be drop down list instead of the button. Also 2 drop drown lists should display where the letters are displayed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible Button</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    drop down list must collapse from here
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vKjqgG

Comment: Exactly yes. but there should be few changes. Below drop down list should  appear only after selecting a value in the drop down list. Also should not disappear after upper one is selected. How can i make these changes?

Comment: see my post with updated codepen - hope this works for you  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your expected result ,use below option

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<select onchange="show()">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
   <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
       <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function show(){
  document.getElementById('demo').style.display='inline-block';

}
```

CSS:

```
#demo{
  position:relative;
  top:150px;
  display:none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vKjqgG

Comment: This is exactly what im looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @user6592730 ..Please mark my post as answered ,if my answer helped your question  :)

Comment: Can you help me to increase its collapsing time? (get more time to collapse) I want it to be little bit slower.